# When I save R graph to pdf, the axis text "℃" turns into dots "...". Why? I'm using Windows platform and Foxit reader

Tags: r, pdf

When I save R graph to pdf, the axis text "℃" turns into dots "...". Why? 
I'm using Windows platform and Foxit reader.
Can't specific symbols appear in pdf files?

Comment: Thank you yms. I'm looking for font package for Foxit reader now.

Comment: Thank you Ricardo. But R graph can be saved as pdf file on Windows platform.

Comment: @Jada I suspect Ricardo was referring to the support for extended character sets or some such.

Answer (score 3):

Use `?plotmath`; it will be more portable in general and less hassle than embedding fonts. E.g.

```
plot(1:10, ylab = expression(DBR ~ Tavg ~ (degree*C))
```

[image]

Or

```
plot(1:10, ylab = expression("DBR Tavg" ~ (degree*C))
```

The `*` operator juxtaposes the two arguments whilst `~` spaces them.

Comment: Thank you Gavin.It's helpful, but in my figure the ylab is "DBR Tavg (℃)". I tried several times but still didn't make it out.

Comment: Do read `?plotmath` - it is fully capable of doing this. Anyway, I have shown one way this can be done in an edit to my Answer. I'll add another way now.

Comment: It worked!! It should be: ylab(expression(paste("BCI Tavg",degree*C))). Thanks a lot! =)

Comment: @Jada You *don't* need `paste` - please see my updated Answer. `paste` just gets in the way here and will cause you more pain in the future with more complex expressions.

Comment: Yes, your updated script is much more gentle. I was just annoyed by the problem that there was no space between "BCI Tavg" and "degree*C" when using "paste".